# Update two tables from another table of another db & server

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table A (trip-data) at server 1 and db X. This table contains (amongst other columns):

1. The ID number of each trip (PK)
2. The serial number(string) of the device which sent the trip-data

Note: fk = foreign key with 1:n relationship

At server 2 and db Y I have the following tables:

1. Table B: The device table with `id_device` and serial number(string)
2. Table C: The machine table with `id_machine`, `device_id`(fk), `company_id`(fk) and `driver_id`(fk)
3. Table D: The trips table with `id_trip`, `device_id`(fk), `machine_id`(fk), `company_id`(fk) and `driver_id`(fk)
4. Table E: 1:1 related to table D with especific data (`trip_id` is fk) including a column for the `trip_id`s of table A

What I want to do (PHP) is update table D & E with the data of table A & C where Table A serial number = Table B serial numbers and Table A `id_trip` != Table E `trip_id`s.

I'm working on that 2 days now and still wasn't able to get it to work. Grateful for any help!

Comment: Table D contains the fk's because it's a data warehouse solution

Comment: Is it question about ability to include tables of two different databases in one sql command? Or you are asking about the code algoritgm?

Comment: it's not necesary to to all in one sql command (and as I learned so far it's not posible)...I'm asking for the best way to realize that in PHP

Comment: Probably, the easiest way, to collect all the tables in one database, perform operations and (optionaly) copy the results back.

Comment: thank you Ruben...I allready solved the problem